# Using excel to verify data sources

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula, data-dump

I want to know if there is a function or formula I can use to verify sample data source 1 (multi-lines) to data source 2 (multi-lines).

Example:
Source 1
Cell A1 (doc) - 123
Cell A2 (div) - SED
Cell A3 (amount)- $100
Cell A4 (line) - 01

Source 2 will be a data dump of different combination of doc, div, amount, and line. I want to know if there is a formula or function that I can do to see if Source 1 matches to any record in Source 2. It has to be a perfect match.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this. The simplest is **MATCH**. MATCH takes a unique value, looks at a list of values, and tells you how many cells in that value was first found. Like so:

```
=MATCH(A1,C5:C10,0)
```

In the above case, assume A1 = "Hello" and C6 = "Hello". Since the match was found in the 2nd cell of the search range, MATCH returns 2. The 0 indicates that only exact matches are desired; -1 / 1 in that space indicates that you have a sorted list and want to take the closest value above/below the unique value.

MATCH can be combined with **INDEX** to take that information and pull in an appropriate value for the related ID. ie: Assume as above, but also that B5:B10 contains, say, a vendor name for the unique ID's found in C5:C10. The vendor name for the 2nd line item of that group can be pulled from column B as follows:

```
=INDEX(B5:B10,2)
```

But this can be combined with MATCH to pull any vendor name where the match existed in column C, like so:

```
=INDEX(B5:B10,MATCH(A1,C5:C10,0))
```

A function often used for these purposes is **VLOOKUP**. VLOOKUP looks at a 2D datablock (say, C5:D10), and finds a specific unique value in the leftmost column. It then returns the value x amount of columns to the right from the leftmost column. Like so [assume that C5:C10 still means vendor names, and you are matching a vendor name in column C to pull the total billings from column E]:

```
=VLOOKUP("ABC Co.", C5:E10, 3,0)
```

This is incredibly similar to the INDEX / MATCH above, with 3 main differences: (1) it is a little simpler if you have a straightforward block of data; (2) Your unique ID key needs to be to the left of what you're searching. So in the above example, if Sales was in column C and vendor name was in column E, you couldn't do a "right-left" search. You would need to instead re-order your data or use a different method; (3) If you insert a new column between C & E, your formula will still say "3rd column to the right", which will no longer point at your invoice number in column E.

If you have specific questions about how to implement this, we need more specific information about how your data is laid out and how you want your results laid out.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I read online about Match and INDEX before asking . I am trying to match the row of data (source 1 from cell A1 - D1) to match any row of data (source 2 from cell A:D). It has to match exactly for the row so I can verify data dump is validated from source 1 and source 2. I am not looking just one cell but a row.

Comment: @SinChan My recommendation would be to have a 'helper column' to the right of both data blocks. Assume data in columns A:E. Column F starting at F1 should read '=A1&B1&C1&D1&E1'. This gives a single string with all text put next to eachother. You can then use index/match on these unique strings.